# CSS3 selecting nested tables using :nth selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-tables

I have set up a mark up. Here's the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/e0st5y0n/32/).
I'm having trouble with figuring out how to select the tables within the table individually. I need to select the `tr` and `td` of the nested tables using the :nth selectors.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood your question but you don't need any `nth` selectors to select the table within a table. All you need is `table table`. From there you would know how to select the `tr` and `td` of the inner table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your markup, the following CSS should do what you're after. If I read your question correctly that is...

```
table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(1) table{background-color:#f0f;}
table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(2) table{background-color:#0ff;}
```

This selects the table row that contains your two inner tables, then selects each table.

A better approach would of course be to use divs with ids/class names. Tables should be used for tabular data, not layout.

Your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e0st5y0n/22/) updated

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was trying to get at. Thank you so much. :D

Answer (score 0):

> you can achieve this kind of elements by following the step by step
>   structure sequence of elements using css this way you can achieve this.

```css
.tableOne table{
    background-color:grey;
    color:white;
}
.tableOne table tr{
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
}
.tableOne table td{
    padding : 10px;    
    color:white;
}
```

hey check out the demo code

[Demo code](https://jsfiddle.net/e0st5y0n/11/)

```css
.tableOne tr td:nth-child(2) table {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    padding:25px;
    border:2px solid yello;
}
```

[updated](https://jsfiddle.net/e0st5y0n/24/)

Comment: @Miss.Vy  check out the answer

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful.

Comment: @Miss.Vy no thanks honor to help you and if you like and if my effort is help-full  and if  you think so upvote or you can accept the answer if you get what you need  :D :D

Comment: This helps with selecting the first nested table. But if I have another nested table https://jsfiddle.net/e0st5y0n/21/ is it possible to select it without using class or id?

Comment: @Miss.Vy hey check out i have updated answer with your diff situation

Answer (score 0):

As Harry mentioned, nth selectors are the wrong choice here as as they find siblings not nested elements. 
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) is a pretty good resource to follow if you want to know more.

Again, as Harry suggested, `table table tr` or `table table td`is probably all you need if your HTML isn't too complex.
They select any tr or td element respectively that exist within a table element that is itself within another table element.

Bare in mind that selectors do not stop at the first match and will continue selecting anything that matches your pattern. That is to say, you could have tables within tables within tables that still match your pattern so you might need to get creative!

You don't really need to use the class `.tableOne` in your selector unless you are going to have other similar structures in your page that you do not want to select :)

If, for whatever reason, you want to have the same style applied to multiple css selectors, separate them with a comma, eg

```
table table tr,
table table td 
{
    /*your style here*/
}
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)'s another link for more information about selectors.

Comment: @Phil.D Thanks you for the clarification and very useful links.

Comment: No problem.
In one of your other comments you link to a demo with two tables within the same parent table but in different cells.
If you wanted to use the nth selector in this case you should apply the nth selector to the `td` element. For example
`.tableOne td:nth-child(2) table`.
The nth selector in this instance would choose the table within the 2nd td element.
Hope this helps!
_Edit: I typed tr instead of td_

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.tableOne tr td:first-child table {
background-color: green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0un0yvgy/

for second one

```
.tableOne tr td:nth-child(2) table {
background-color: red;
}
```